# Display ESRI Shapefiles in a map in a browser. (Non Google Maps)

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, mapping, esri

I have a series of shape files that I need to render as a map on a webpage. I have an asp.net server although I would prefer something that will work on my leased servers from Inmotion Hosting. (They are linux servers). I would like to find an easy to set up opensource or freeware solution if at all possible. This cannot be overlayed over Google maps. It is just a map of the County I live in and that is all that needs to be shown.  The shape files consist of the Streets, boundary lines, street names, etc. Each one is a seperate shape file.  This map will need to be zoomable as well.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I do not have a copy of ArcGIS so I cannot do any conversions with it. Although I have QuantumGIS installed. It's server is giving me issues though.

Comment: If you really don't care about doing anything other than displaying them... [maybe this?](http://badassjs.com/post/845509816/rendering-binary-shapefiles-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render your shapefile on the server and send the 
results to the browser, then you can use a Map Server or WMS Provider like **GeoServer** (http://geoserver.org/).

GeoServer is an open source software server that allows users to share and edit geospatial data.

When you serve your shapefiles in GeoServer, you can use any libraries like **OpenLayers** to display this data in browser (http://openlayers.org/).